# Retorno 3 meses anteriores desde o dia 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

Toda sexta-feira preciso gerar um relatório que me traz transações feitas nos 3 últimos meses. Porém, tenho que pegar desde o dia 1 de cada mês, por exemplo, estamos no mês 9, então tenho que pegar todas as transações desde o dia 01/06. 
Sempre faço a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT 
    Z.ID_CONTA
    ,W.ID_TRANSACAO
    ,Y.DS_TIPO_TRANSACAO
    ,W.DT_ORIGEM
    ,W.VL_TRANSACAO
FROM T_CONTA Z
LEFT JOIN W_TRANSACAO W ON Z.ID_CONTA = W.ID_CONTA
LEFT JOIN T_TIPOTRANSACAO Y ON W.CD_TIPO_TRANSACAO = Y.CD_TIPO_TRANSACAO 
WHERE MONTH(DT_ORIGEM) >= MONTH(GETDATE()) - 3 AND YEAR(DT_ORIGEM) = 2018
```

Sempre deu certo, porém agora estou pensando quando virar o ano, para não ter que ficar mudando sempre.

Comment: Seu bando de dados é `MySQL`?

Comment: Boa tarde, é o SQL Server.

Comment: Troque `2018` por `YEAR(GETDATE())`

Comment: `GETDATE()` retorna a data atual

Comment: Já pensei nisso, porém quando for jan/19, terei que trazer os dados de out/18, nov/18, dez/18 e jan/19

Comment: @fercs89 (1) Como a coluna DT_ORIGEM está em tabela unida por LEFT JOIN, nem sempre haverá valor para comparar; o que fazer, nesses casos? (2) Como está declarada a coluna DT_ORIGEM?

Comment: @JoséDiz não entendi a pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a função `GetDate()` para retornar a data atual e a partir da data retornada retire 3 meses com a função `DATEADD`:

```
SELECT 
    Z.ID_CONTA,
    W.ID_TRANSACAO,
    Y.DS_TIPO_TRANSACAO,
    W.DT_ORIGEM,
    W.VL_TRANSACAO
FROM T_CONTA Z
LEFT JOIN W_TRANSACAO W ON Z.ID_CONTA = W.ID_CONTA
LEFT JOIN T_TIPOTRANSACAO Y ON W.CD_TIPO_TRANSACAO = Y.CD_TIPO_TRANSACAO 
WHERE DT_ORIGEM >= CONCAT(
    YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())),
    '-',
    MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())), '-01'
)
```

Veja mais sobre a função `DATEADD` [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Coloquei essa query e ela me retornou os dados desde mar/18, ou seja, um período bem maior do que eu preciso.

Comment: Tinha um `-3` a mais ali, corrigi

Comment: agora deu certo, muito obrigada! =D

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Quando possível reescreva o código, pois a cláusula WHERE pode retornar resultado errado. Por exemplo, se o mês corrente for fevereiro/2018, ela retorna somente linhas de dezembro/2017. Além disso, o código não é _sargable_.

Comment: @JoséDiz seria mais ou menos isso?

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Desculpe a demora em responder. A modificação que fez já está melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Outro jeito que consegui:

```
SELECT 
Z.ID_CONTA,
W.ID_TRANSACAO,
Y.DS_TIPO_TRANSACAO,
W.DT_ORIGEM,
W.VL_TRANSACAO FROM T_CONTA Z LEFT JOIN W_TRANSACAO W ON Z.ID_CONTA = W.ID_CONTA LEFT JOIN T_TIPOTRANSACAO Y ON W.CD_TIPO_TRANSACAO = Y.CD_TIPO_TRANSACAO  WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, DT_ORIGEM, GETDATE()) < 4
```