# SELECT de cliente com pagamento dos últimos dois meses (60 dias)

Tags: sql, query, tsql

Possuo uma tabela TBCLIENTES onde possuem as colunas: NOME, DATA_PAGAMENTO, FORMA_PAGAMENTO. Preciso saber os clientes que pagaram nos ultimos 2 meses (60 dias) na forma de pagamento BOLETO. Como consigo realizar esse SELECT na data para puxar os ultimos 2 meses, com essa condição: através de Lotérica com forma envio correios.

Comment: Isso responde sua pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/332929/retorno-3-meses-anteriores-desde-o-dia-1

Comment: Sim, obrigado Maria Eduarda.
Procurei de outras formas e não cheguei nesta resposta, MUITO obrigado.

Comment: Apenas defina mais precisamente o período a ser considerado. Considerando a data de hoje (06/02/2021) com "últimos 2 meses" você quer após 07/12/2020 ou entre 01/12/2020 e 31/01/2021? Com "60 dias" seria de 08/12/2020 em diante?

Comment: Bom dia, na verdade é assim. O cliente ele possui faturas e eu preciso das 2 faturas dele neste últimos 2 meses que foram pagos em loteria com forma de envio correios.